# Subtracting a constant value from one column when condition on another column holds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame that has the following columns: *foo* and *bar*.  *foo* values are integers and *bar* values are strings.  For each row, if the value of *bar* is some particular value, say, 'ABC', then I want to set the value of the *foo* column (for that row) to its current value minus one.

For example, I want to convert this data frame:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 98 | 'ABC' |
| 53 | 'DEF' |
| 22 | 'ABC' |
| 34 | 'FGH' |

converted to this:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 97 | 'ABC' |
| 53 | 'DEF' |
| 21 | 'ABC' |
| 34 | 'FGH' |

How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the `.loc` on dataframe:

```
CONSTANT_VAL = 1
df.loc[df['bar'] == 'ABC', 'foo'] -= CONSTANT_VAL
```

Answer (score 1):

`.loc` and `np.where` both can work as a possible solution here.

`np.where` works like an if-else statement, where it checks whether the condition is met, which in this case is `df['bar'] == 'ABC'`, and if its true, subtract 1 from df['foo'], else dont do anything.

```
df['foo'] = np.where(df['bar']=='ABC', df['foo']-1, df['foo'])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   foo  bar
0   98  ABC
1   53  DEF
2   22  ABC
3   34  FGH

In [3]: df.loc[df.bar=='ABC', 'foo'] = df[df.bar=='ABC']['foo']-1

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   foo  bar
0   97  ABC
1   53  DEF
2   21  ABC
3   34  FGH
```